# How to receive uplink data on my webpage from Sigfox server?

Tags: php, json, networking, callback

I am a new bee to sigfox. I want to receive sensors' data from sigfox server to my webpage. I defined a callback function as in the pic below in sigfox. I want to know how to receive the JSON data in my webpage. My web page is running on a personal apache web server with a public ip.

I am using php. Like normally use a curl call to receive json from any server using its URL. Here in sigfox case, what source i.e. url I specify in curl to retrieve json data from it. OR what mechanism to use. I searched web & forum but didn't find any answer. Sigfox has a nice description about how to receiver data to an email but not for a custom url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The body of the callback should be something like this

```
{
    "deviceId": "{device}",
    "time": {time},
    "seqNumber": {seqNumber},
    "data": "{data}",
    "reception": [{ "id": "{station}", "RSSI": {rssi}, "SNR": {snr} }],
    "duplicate": {duplicate},
    "ack": {ack},
}
```

Other parts in your config seem ok, just write your endpoint in `sigfoxdata.php` to handle the data (eg. parse it).